# What are the differences between Spider-man and Ultimate Spider-man?

Tags: comics, marvel, spider-man

In Spider-men we see the normal and Ultimate universe Spider-mans meet.  The normal Spider-man is surprised by Ultimate Spider-man's venom sting and electrified webs.  What other differences in powers do they have, and why is there a difference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Peter Parker, Spider-Man of Earth-616 and Miles Morales, Spider-Man of Earth-1610 are two different characters who share a continuity inside of the Marvel Multiverse of stories. The two characters shared an origin story in that Peter Parker was the original Spider-Man of both universes.**

Peter Parker of Ultimate Earth (#1610) was killed and Miles Morales takes his place. Miles gains his powers after a spider affected by a serum created by Oscorp bites him and gives him similar powers to Peter Parker. Parker's blood was used in the serum, so their physical powers are the similar.

- Both Spider-Men have superhuman strength and physical durability capable of lifting 10-20 tons under ideal conditions. Morales might be less strong since he is much younger than Peter Parker of Earth-616. Both are able to survive physical damage that would kill a normal human.
- Both have superhuman reflexes and heightened physical agility beyond that of an Olympic level athlete.
- Both had an psychic ability to detect danger which was dubbed, "spider-sense" but Parker's ability was lost and Morales has yet to develop any sufficient skill in the use of his.
- Parker's spider-sense was once so sophisticated he could use it to avoid any danger around him. It was, occasionally unreliable versus certain enemies, such as Venom.
- Both Spider-Men can cling to any surface using only their hands and feet. Parker has been able to exhibit some level of superstrength with his clinging. Morales is still learning and can only lift his weight.

Earth-616 Spider-Man has had other powers including organic web-shooters, night vision, and stingers. But with all of the recent reboots of the characters, those powers are in limbo and may no longer be considered canon.

However, the spider which affected Morales gives him additional powers that Spider-Man of Earth 616 does not have including:

- limited invisibility - he is able to turn himself and his clothing invisible to normal vision.
- venom strike - a form of electrically delivered charge that is able to paralyze people. It can be sent as a charge through conductive materials

Since Spider-Man's gadgets have varied over the decades, they are a much less interesting part of the legend of Spider-Man. Parker has experimented with a variety of technologies and with the help of Tony Stark has quite an exotic suit of powered armor if and when he needs it. Since Morales lives in the Ultimate Universe, he will more than likely end up dealing with or working with the SHIELD of that universe and will be equipped with a variety of tools and weapons they think will work best for him.

As to why there is a difference, the benefit of multiple universes is to allow Marvel's writers to experiment with telling different stories, hopefully in better ways with equally gratifying results.

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on which "Ultimate Spiderman" you are speaking of.

The 616 ("our") Spiderman was bitten by a **radioactively mutated** spider, in most cases [not counting the inclusion of him as a "Spider totem", and thus giving it a *mystical* significance.] Generally speaking, his feats have shown him to be stronger, faster, more durable and more experienced than either of the ultimate versions. This should be natural, given that *our* Spiderman is older [late 20s to **early** 30s] based on Marvel's sliding timeline, and thus either his powers have developed further, or he's had more practice in maximizing their potential. Either way, he's been shown **stopping planes with his legs** at one point, so I think its fair to say he can handle a bit more than 20 tons, maxed out.

[image]

That by itself accounts for some difference, but there is more.

In the ***Spiderverse*** crossover, it was stated that Peter's Spider sense was stronger than Miles Morales, but *not* as strong as the Spider Woman Silk, whose border on psychic visions as opposed to wide range environmental sensitivity/precognition. It should be noted that Spidey and Silk were both bitten by the *same* radioactive spider as teenagers (which, interestingly enough, makes them both susceptible to each other natural pheromones, which has some... *interesting* affects.) Why *her* powers developed different (lesser strength, greater spider sense and natural webbing) is unknown, but could be put down to anything from differences in gender, to genome structure to the spider *continuing* to mutate.

The  **Ultimate Peter Parker** was the *first* Spiderman of the *Ultimates* universe, and he got his powers similarly to "our" Peter (fifteen-year-olds touring a science facility bitten by a super spider), with one key difference; the *Ultimates* spider was *genetically modified* not by radiation, but an experimental drug from Oscorp called Oz-0x. This was *not* the same spider that bit Miles Morales; a *new* version of the drug was created, tested on a new bug sometime later, and that's how Mile's powers came about.

The *Peter* of this world, however, was shown to be a bit faster than our Spiderman, but less durable, with a higher metabolism/quicker healing, and way, waaaay weaker (his strength seemed to max out at 8 tons, unless **severely** pushed, in which he could go to 10). His spider sense was also shown to be someone slower, with Otto Octavius (one of the Oscorp scientists) saying he has developed the capacity of a "long distance runner or triathlete" and a "highly advanced *feeling* mechanism," so his sense is less "precognition" and more "Extra/boosted sensory input."

Miles Morales, as explained earlier, follows suit to the Ultimate Peter; being younger, he's understandably weaker, but seems to take to his natural agility and quickness much more easily. Miles auxiliary powers (bio-electricity and natural camouflage) can either be put down to the differences in the Oz serum,  their different genetic structures, or in the spider itself.